# What is causing my computer to be slow all of a sudden? New version of Firefox/Ubuntu? Script error? Old computer?

Tags: ubuntu, firefox

A script on this page may be busy, or it may have stopped responding. You can stop the script now, or you can continue to see if the script will complete.

When the above shows up, I click continue and am able to proceed.  I would like to know if whatever is causing the above could be causing my computer to be extremely slow.  A newer version of Ubuntu/Firefox was put on my computer and this is when the script notice started showing up and my computer started running extremely slow.  My son says it is because my computer is too old.  Is this so or could it be something else?  (With the older version it ran fine.)  Thank you, Deb.

Comment: We would need to know the specific script causing the problem in question to answer this

Comment: Since you titled with "all the sudden"... my first responses would be, have you Restarted the system? and have you run a maleware scan?

Answer (score 0):

That sounds like a common Firefox/Mozilla message when a bug in a web site causes a problem. Try stopping and restarting Firefox. Or right-click on the tabs and choose "close" until it clears up or you close them all. You should not be getting this message repeatedly.